# EXCEL Search items from one sheet to another and return true/false

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to use a formula to find a value from SHEETA!A212 and see if this value is used anywhere in SHEETB!A2:K500. SHEET B does not use columns, as values can be located anywhere in between this range(array). looking to return true/false in

Appreciate the assistance
excel '16

Comment: please add some sample data to your question, in its current state it's very difficult to understand it.

Comment: Your Values are numbers or text?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lookup Function in the column B of sheet A if you have more then one value to look for you should write the following formula in the same row, if you are looking for A212 in sheet A write the formula in B212:

**=IF(ISERROR(LOOKUP(A212,SHEETB!A2:K500)),"No Match","Match")**
You will see Match if it is located in the array SHEETB!A2:K500 and No Match if not.
If your Data is numbers your array should be in ascending order to get a result with Lookup